# How to focus to next grid cell after reloading the kendo mvc grid

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

we are using kendo MVC grid with inline editing, after changing some value in grid 
we need to reload the grid for showing server side calculation values (some more calculations needed), then i cannot able to focus to  next grid cell after this reloading.

Is there is anyway to focus to next grid cell after reloading the grid

Comment: Any one can help me..? i want to focus to next cell of grid after reloading the grid. its focus is missing once reloading completed. i am using grid.editCell(curCell.next());

Comment: this issue is solved using bellow code...thax all....   var grid = $("#grdAdjustmentDtls").data("kendoGrid");
grid.editCell(grid.tbody.find("tr").eq(rowIndex).find("td").eq(colIndex));

Answer (score 0):

this issue is solved using bellow code...

var grid = $("#grdAdjustmentDtls").data("kendoGrid"); grid.editCell(grid.tbody.find("tr").eq(rowIndex).find("td").eq(colIndex));

need to keep editing rowIndex and columnIndex globally before going to reload the grid

thax all....